# C# , How to write RegEx.Replace to replace value for an xml element?

Tags: c#, regex

Have a xml string, goal is to replace an xml element value to a fixed string, i.e. for blah blah blah replace it to fixed value, I am thinking to use RegEx.Replace instead of loading the string to a DOM model and replace.

Could anyone please help on how to write this regular expression? essentially the goal is to match everything inside element tag 'abc'

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This article tells you what you need to know: **[XML is not Regular](http://welbog.homeip.net/glue/53/XML-is-not-regular)**

> Ignoring the most obvious solution to their problem (which would be to use a pre-existing XML parser), they think they should use regular expressions (regex for short). Now they have two problems.
>
> **Use regular expressions only on *regular* languages.**

That said, there are [many sites](https://www.google.com/search?q=xml%20regular%20expression) that purport to offer guidance on writing regular expressions for XML.  **They are all wrong**.  But they exist, and you can use them at your own risk.

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, don't.

Process the XML normally, with a `XmlDocument`, `Xml.Linq` or `XmlReader/Writer`, it's what they are for, cover all kinds of edge cases we couldn't even imagine, and above all, are proven to work.

Don't use a regex for this, please . . . just don't.

My two cents.

*let the downvoting begin*

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are not suitable for processing markup. Among other flaws, they won't work if elements can be nested:

```
<abc> ... <abc> ... </abc> ... </abc>
```

They are also unable to distinguish a comment from a non-comment.

You need a real XML parser.

Comment: no, they won't be nested due to business rules, all i want to archieve is to simply replace anything inside xml tag <abc>...</abc> to a constant value <abc>new value</abc>

Comment: Tommy, I must stress what everyone else has previously written regarding using RegEx on markup. For this reason, I've not submitted an answer incase you happened to mark it as correct. Proceed with caution: `<abc>\s*(.+?)\s*</abc>`

Answer (score 3):

**Regular** expressions are meant to be used on **[regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)** languages.  XML is a non-regular language.  As such, regular expressions cannot be used to properly parse anything written in it. You will need to use a real XML parser, which can be found in the numerous libraries available in C#, to do it.